# PHP strpos function conflicts with "../" file directory system

Tags: php, mysql, post, directory

I've created a file directory system. here there is a function to make the directories and I want to prevent users making directories in ../ ie up one folder therefore I've created an if statement with strpos to search for it. Here's the code:

```
<div class="FormElement">
  <form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="newFolder" id="newFolder" class="newFolder"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
  </form>

  <?php
    $uniqueUserPath = $_SESSION['userPath'];
    $folderName = $_POST['newFolder'];
    $makeFolder = $uniqueUserPath . "/" . $folderName;
    // mkdir($uniqueUserPath . "/" . $folderName);

    if (strpos($folderName, "../") == true) {
      echo 'there is a slash.';
    } else {
      mkdir($uniqueUserPath . "/" . $folderName);
      echo 'there isnt a slash';
    }
  ?>
</div>
```

And if you type in there "../" it stil echo's there isn't a slash and more importantly it will start making the directories in a folder outside of the users folder.

Any help would be appreciated
kind regards,

Comment: Make use of `realpath`

Comment: can you give me an example please as I don't get how to use it after reading the php documentation :)

Comment: `=== true` because `0 == true` but you want `!== false`.

Comment: There are examples on the manual page http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Comment: `strpos` doesn't return a boolean unless it can't find the needle. So `!== false` is what you want.

Comment: Are the users supposed to only create one subdirectory level instead of e.g. `a/b/c`? In that case [basename](http://docs.php.net/basename) might help.

Comment: they should be able to create as many subdirectory levels as they like. but just not "../" ie the ability to create folders outside of their directory upon login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strpos($folderName, "../") == true` needs to be `strpos($folderName, "../") !== false`

The reason is because if it finds a match it returns the character index of the match, (e.g. 5) which then gets evaluated to true because `5 == true` is true.

It returns boolean `false` if there is no match so you should be looking for that.

Comment: if i wanted to prevent a user from typing in <?php ?> how would i do that? or at least to escape the string, of course without the mysql function.

Comment: Check out [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags) for that.  It will also strip PHP tags.